Why no traffic appear in Network tab of Browser Dev Tools, even though there MUST be?
I'm using pad.riseup which interactively allow to modify the text, so there MUST BE active traffic. So how to show it in the Firefox dev tools? And why it doesn't show up?
Yeah I clicked on "All" to show everything, but appears nothing, so it isn't even a WebSocket I guess...
I expected to have the traffic showing up.
